# Bootstarp Vue - Form Tags - How to know which tag removed from the list?

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am new to Vue and I would like to ask about From Tag
By default, I fill the Form-tag list with a list of all categories and if user removes any category (tag) from the tag list, I would like to know which one he removed...

I checked Bootstrap vue document but they have got new tag id and new tag value, not mentioning anything about the selected and removed one.

```html
<b-form-tags input-id="tags-basic"
  v-model="selectedCat" 
  class="col-12" 
  placeholder="Selected Categories"
  @@input="appCatFilter()"                                   
>
</b-form-tags>
```

[Image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX44r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `watcher` to watch your `b-form-tags` v-model, to catch any changes made to it.

The watcher is passed in the new value, and the old value. 
So if you compare the two, you can find what was removed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      value: ["apple", "orange"]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value(newVal, oldVal) {
      /* Finds the value(s) that  got removed */
      const removed = oldVal.filter(v => !newVal.includes(v));
      if(removed && removed.length > 0) {
        alert(`${removed} was removed from the list`);
        /* Do something here */
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.14.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.14.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <label for="tags-basic">Type a new tag and press enter</label>
    <b-form-tags input-id="tags-basic" v-model="value" class="mb-2"></b-form-tags>
    <p>Value: {{ value }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Just quick question a bit confused,about this code  const removed = oldVal.filter((value) => !newVal.includes(value));   why we used value in here. we have old and new data already. Probably i am wrong but i modify this code like this, is it wrong? const removed = oldVal.filter(e => !newVal.includes(e));

Comment: @AdilSari That's the same I'm doing. It might be confusing because of bad naming. but i'm using the `value` from the filter and not `this.value`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it slightly more clear.

Comment: I thought we are using this value :) now it makes sense. Thank you.